# How to delete rows from custom table within a time interval?

Tags: functions

I need to apply this PHP Rule to remove records into a custom table

```
$query = "DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE Date < now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;
```

I'not albe to figure out how to implement this line by applying

```
$wpdb->delete( $table, $where, $where_format );
```

I tried with this here below but it didn't work.

```
$wpdb->delete( $table_name, Date < now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Please can you help me?

NOTE:
Date:  is a name of the column where date is written
I need to remove all rows that are older than 30 days from "today"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way

```
    $wpdb->query(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE Date < now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY")
    );
```